# Change innerhtml on node server side

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

Basically I want to know if it's possible to set the innerHTML from the server side of a node.js server. The following is the basic idea:

client:

```
socket.emit("some message");
```

server:

```
socket.on("some message", function() {
  document.getElementByID("someElement").innerHTML = "apple"
  document.getElementByID("anotherElement").innerHTML = "banana"
});
```

I'm trying to simply and efficiently edit multiple html elements when one server request is made. I'm not sure if something similar to the above is possible or if making individual emits for each field and listening for each response from the server is the only way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "innerHTML" on a node server. "innerHTML" is a property of HTML elements in a browser, and can only be changed by events in a browser.

Comment: I figured there was no HTML attributes on the server side of things, I was wondering if there was any equivalent to what I described.

Comment: nope... why do you want to make this change? so every page after has the new data instead of the old data?

Comment: The purpose of this would be say the user clicks a button which brings up details about what they clicked. There would be many fields here and if it could be done by sending one message to the server to grab all the data it would be much simpler and cleaner, I'd imagine, than having to send a message for each field.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<p id="main">nothing yet!</p>
```

in JS: document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = "the file is created!"

that is, initially you must put something in the p tag. if you let the p tag field "empty", then you can't change the dom from JS.